# ERROR: Cannot redeclare PHP en la misma función

Tags: php, function

¡Buenas tardes!
Se que este error suele salir cuando llamas a dos funciones de la misma manera, pero es que es la única que se llama así.

El Error concretamente es:

> Cannot redeclare correctDate() (previously declared in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\API-management-medicalDB\tools.php:9) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\API-management-medicalDB\tools.php on line 19

El archivo Tools es este:

```
<?php

/**
 * This function creates a date with the format of SQL.
 * @param date the date that will have the correct format.
 * @return aux the date with the appropriate format.
 * 
*/
function correctDate($date)
{
    $aux = null;
    if (is_null($date)) {
        $aux = date("Y-m-d");
    } else {
        //To have the right format
        $aux = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    }
    return $aux;
}

/**
 * This function creates a date with the format of SQL.
 * @param date the date that will have the correct format.
 * @return date the date with the appropriate format.
 * 
*/
function correct2Dates($date_start, $date_end)
{
    if (is_null($date_start)) {
        $date_start = date("Y-m-d");
    } else {
        //To have the right format
        $date_start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_start));
    }
    if (is_null($date_end)) {
        $date_end = $date_start;
    } else {
        //To have the right format
        $date_end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_end));
    }
    return array($date_start, $date_end);
}

/**
 * This function creates a time with the format of SQL.
 * @param time_start when something started
 * @return time_start the time with appropriate format.
 * 
*/
function correctTime($time_start)
{
    if (is_null($time_start)) {
        $time_start = date("H:i:s");
    } else {
        //To have the right format
        $time_start = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time_start));
    }
    return $time_start;
}

/**
 * This function creates two times with the format of SQL.
 * @param time_start the time when all started.
 * @param duration it indicates the time something lasted.
 * @return time_start,duration the times with the appropriate format.  
 * 
*/
function correct2Times($time_start, $duration)
{

    if (is_null($time_start)) {
        $time_start = date("H:i:s");
    } else {
        //To have the right format
        $time_start = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time_start));
    }
    if (is_null($duration)) {
        $duration = date("H:i:s", strtotime("1:00:00"));
    } else {
        //To have the right format
        $duration = date("H:i:s", strtotime($duration));
    }
    return array($time_start, $duration);
}

/**
 * This class is needed to access to some tables of data base
 * and their information
*/
class Tools
{
    private $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        include "conection.php";
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }
    /**
     * This functions gives you the ID of all the classifiers which description is similar to the given.
     * @param name the classifying that we are searching for.
     * @return this_array is an Array<Array> with all the information.
     */
    function getIDClassifying(String $name)
    {
        $this_array = array();
        $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM clasificador WHERE UPPER(descripcion) LIKE UPPER('%" . $name . "%') ");
        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($a_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $actual_array = array(
                    "name" => $a_res['descripcion'],
                    "type" => $a_res['tipo'],
                    "ID" => $a_res['IDCalificador']
                );
                $this_array . array_push($actual_array);
            }
        }

        return $this_array;
    }

    /**
     * This functions gives you the type of one classifier.
     * @param IDClassifying the classifier that we are searching for.
     * @return type the type of the classifier given.
     */

    function getClassifyingType(int $IDClassifying)
    {
        $type = null;
        $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT tipo FROM clasificador WHERE IDClasificador = '" . $IDClassifying . "' ");
        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            $a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $type = $a_res['tipo'];
        }
        return $type;
    }


    /**
     * This functions gives you the ID of all the digestive symptoms which name is similar to the given.
     * @param name the name of the symptoms
     * @return this_array is an Array<Array> with all the information.
     */
    function getIDDigestivo(String $name)
    {
        $this_array = array();
        $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM digestivo WHERE UPPER(nombre) LIKE UPPER('%" . $name . "%')  ");
        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($a_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $actual_array = array(
                    "name" => $a_res['nombre'],
                    "ID" => $a_res['IDDIgestivo']
                );
                $this_array . array_push($actual_array);
            }
        }
        return $this_array;
    }

    /**
     * This functions gives you all the emotions which name is similar to the given.
     * @param name the name of the symptoms
     * @return this_array is an Array with all the information.
     */
    function getEmotion(String $emotion)
    {
        $this_array = array();
        $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM emocion WHERE UPPER(nombreEmocion) LIKE UPPER('%" . $name . "%')  ");
        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($a_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $this_array . array_push($a_res['nombreEmocion']);
            }
        }
        return $this_array;
    }
    /**
     * This functions gives you the ID of all the general symptoms which name is similar to the given.
     * @param name the name of the symptoms
     * @return this_array is an Array<Array> with all the information.
     */
    function getIDGeneral(String $name)
    {
        $this_array = array();
        $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM general WHERE UPPER(nombre) LIKE UPPER('%" . $name . "%')  ");
        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($a_res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $actual_array = array(
                    "name" => $a_res['nombre'],
                    "ID" => $a_res['IDGeneral']
                );
                $this_array . array_push($actual_array);
            }
        }
        return $this_array;
    }
}
```

El error concretamente lo da aquí:

```
function correctDate($date) //Línea 9
{
    $aux = null;
    if (is_null($date)) {
        $aux = date("Y-m-d");
    } else {
        //To have the right format
        $aux = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
    }
    return $aux;
} //Línea 19
```

Lo llamo aquí:

```
function getRecordByTime($user, $day, $time_start, $time_end)
{
    //it checks if it has the correct format
    $day = correctDate($day);
    //it checks if the times have the correct format
    $times = correct2Times($time_start,$time_end);
    $time_start = $times[0];
    $time_end = $times[1];
    //Maybe the user don't remember exactly the moment 
    //so we search the records during a short period of time before $time_start.
    // the time - 30 min
    $time_start_aux = $time_start - (0 * 0 * 30 * 0);

    //I Find the record
    $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM aniade_registro WHERE correo = '" . $user . "' and fecha == '" . $day . "' and hora <= '.$time_start.' and hora >= '.$time_start_aux.' ");

    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            //Now we have to search if there is any symptom
            $this->checkDuration($a_res['IDRegistro'], $time_end);
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

He revisado con el propio editor y en todos los archivos solo está la función cuando la llaman. Y en el propio archivo de Tools está 1 vez.

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando? ¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: La función `correctDate()` ya fue declarada en la línea 9 del archivo `tools.php` tal y como dice el mensaje de error: *`... previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\API-management-medicalDB\tools.php:9)`*. Revisa que ocurre en la línea 19, porque allí es posible que hagas un `include` o `require` de un archivo que contenga también esa función.

Comment: OJO, el mensaje no dice que el error sea en la línea 9, lo que dice el mensaje es esto: *`No se puede volver a declarar correctDate() (**previamente declarado** en C:\ xampp\htdocs\API-management-medicalDB\tools.php: 9) en **C:\xampp\htdocs\API-management-medicalDB\tools.php en la línea 19`***. Realmente el error ocurre en la línea `19`, dice que ahí declaras una nueva función llamada `correctDate()`. Ahora bien, el archivo que muestras no se corresponde, porque ahí en la línea 19 no hay declaración de función, parece que es un mensaje viejo ¿? posterior a la modificación del archivo.

Comment: La cosa es que en el error dice que es en tools, y el fichero que he puesto es ese, además que como he señalado en la línea 19 hay un } y luego pasa a otra función

Comment: Por eso, pienso que ese error es anterior, cuando quizá en la línea 19 tenías un duplicado de la función, eso se intuye porque unas pocas líneas más abajo hay esto:  `function correct2Dates ( ... )` yo creo que ese log de errores es anterior, si puedes revisa actualmente el log de errores buscando el último error al respecto que te dirá exactamente en qué líneas se encuentra el problema. El código que muestras no es coherente con ese mensaje de error.

Comment: Acabo de probar una cosa, es poner el include de tools en el fichero de prueba y quitarlo de todos los demás y resulta que ha dejado de dar ese error. Así que lo que pasaba es que como estaba el include cargaba varias veces el fichero por así decirlo y por ello parecía que había más funciones cuando eran la misma. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuando incluyes el mismo archivo desde dos o más lugares se recomienda: a) Revisar la lógica de tu sistema para evitar la necesidad de dos o más includes. b) Usar `include_once 'nombre-archivo.php';`

Comment: oh muchas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta

Comment: Esto ocurre por que tienes un requiere o include a ese archivo o de alguna forma si tienes un autoload este estara intentando cargar dos veces ese archivo, el problema es que tienes funciones publicas fuera de clases... y al intentar acceder al archivo una segunda ves, el php intentara declarar una nueva vez la funcion... esto es un error de programacion, usar `function_exists(` no deberia ser una solucion ... ya que estarias intentando parchear un error de logica con más codigo.

Comment: lo ideal es evaluar en donde estas insertando ese archivo y evaluar la forma correcta de hacerlo, asi como la forma correcta de manejar el codigo contenido dentro del archivo, si estas usando composer autoload, lo ideal seria colocar las funciones globales en un archivo php separado/independiente de los archivos con clases ...

Answer (score -1):

El ***error de función ya declarada*** te indica el punto en que una función se define por segunda vez, es independiente de si llamas o no a la función en tu aplicación.

La declaración de funciones debería hacerse en un bloque como:

```
if (!function_exists('theFunctionName')) {
    function theFunctionName()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

para evitar el error al ejecutar el programa.
Esto presenta un posible problema: si una función con ese nombre ya existe, esa será la que use en la aplicación y seguramente implementa una lógica diferente a la que escribiste. Para saber si esto ocurre, suelo añadir un bloque `else` que grava un log de *debug*.

El ***error de función ya definida***, por mi experiencia, se da por ***tres posibles causas***:

1. Ya has escrito una función con el mismo nombre en el mismo u otro archivo.
2. Estas cargando el archivo donde defines la función más de una vez.
3. Estas definiendo una función que ya existe como función nativa en PHP.

Para saber si estas en el primer caso, puedes buscar en tu editor sobre el proyecto:

```
on theFunctionName(
```

*Puede darse también el caso de que una librería de terceros defina la función. Busca, también, en "vendor" o el directorio donde se carguen librerías externas*.

Si no estas en el primer caso, pasa a los siguientes. El segundo suele darse si haces `require` de tus ficheros directamente, si es así `require_once` suele ser una solución, pero deberías ver, porque se esta ejecutando ese `require` más de una vez.

Para detectar el tercer caso, hay que hacer online una búsqueda del nombre de la función asociándolo a PHP.

El tercer caso puede darse en el momento de escribir la función o en el futuro: escribes una función que no se encuentra definida en la versión actual de PHP y todo correcto, pero si provocará un error al actualizar a una versión que la incluye si no tratas la definición adecuadamente.
Ocasionalmente, interesa definir una función que no existe en la versión de PHP actual pero se va a usar en futuras versiones, p.e. PHP 8 incorpora `str_contains` (también *Laravel* con versiones mas antiguas). Si tuvieras que trabajar con PHP 7, por ejemplo, puedes definir la función con la firma y uso que tiene en PHP 8. Ahora tu programa usará `str_contains` en PHP 7, con tu definición, y la "definición nativa" en PHP 8.